# Как правильно использовать objectManager в yandex map api

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Я разрабатываю приложение с поиском ПВЗ - пунктов выдачи заказов.В пределах видимости карты на карту динамически подгружаются ПВЗ.

Как это происходит:

1. Я отправляю периметр охватывающий экраном карты на API shiptor(это сыйт службы доставки)
2. В ответ он мне присылает список доступных ПВЗ находящихся в области карты.
3. Я эти ПВЗ ложу в objectManager  и они появляются на карте. При перемещении карты или ее увеличении я снова отправляю периметр карты на shiptor и он мне также отправляет список ПВЗ, Я удаляю старый objectManager  запихиваю данные в новый objectManager и вставляю в него новые пришедшие данные.

При такой логике, приложение работает тяжеловато, подскажите другие варианты использования objectManager.

```
objectManager.removeAll();
objectManager.add(overlay);
```

Comment: А почему нельзя сразу загрузить полный список ПВЗ? Например для региона. Оверлеи будут созданы только для тех объектов, которые попадают в текущую область показа карты. Это написано в документации - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/object-manager/about.html

Comment: Не подходит такой метод, т.к. сразу все точки выгрузить на карту не возможно. ПО нескольким причинам. Во-первых общий размер всех точек, а их 86 тыс. составляет 5 мб, пользователю с плохим интернетом не возможно будет пользоваться картой. Во-вторых на бэке идут сложные математические расчеты всех ПВЗ, там фильтруются ПВЗ попавшие на карту под габариты груза,массу и прочее. Поэтому не возможно сразу всю страну отфильтровать. Поэтому данный подход не уместен.

Answer (score 0):

Как посоветовали в комментарии выше, лучше загрузить все объекты сразу. Когда вам нужно отобразить только часть, можно установить [функцию-фильтр](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager.html#method_detail__setFilter), например по попаданию в bounds карты.

Comment: Не подходит такой метод, т.к. сразу все точки выгрузить на карту не возможно. ПО нескольким причинам. Во-первых общий размер всех точек, а их 86 тыс. составляет 5 мб, пользователю с плохим интернетом не возможно будет пользоваться картой. Во-вторых на бэке идут сложные математические расчеты всех ПВЗ, там фильтруются ПВЗ попавшие на карту под габариты груза,массу и прочее. Поэтому не возможно сразу всю страну отфильтровать. Поэтому данный подход не уместен.